# convert String to Date on GWT

Tags: gwt

How do I convert String to Date or Date to String using GWT 2.0.3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the methods on the `java.util.Date` class itself: `parse(String s)` and `toString()`. Although the first is deprecated it is the method to use with GWT. If you want more control over how the Date is formatted, when converting to String use the GWT specific class: `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat`. It will format the date given a pattern, similar to Java's own `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 11):

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat;
import java.util.Date;

...

public Date getDate(String dateString) {
    Date result = null;
    try {
        DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        result = dateTimeFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ignore
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert Date to StringFormat

```
    import com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    ...
    public String getStringFormat(Date inputDate){
    String strFormat = null;
    try{
    DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY");
    strFormat = dateTimeFormat.format(inputDate);
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strFormat;
    }
```