# Conversion between String and Date in client-side GWT

Tags: java, gwt, type-conversion

Using `SimpleDateFormat` is a standard way to do String <-> Date conversion in Java.

But this class is not present in GWT [JRE Emulation library](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation?hl=pl-PL) so we can't use it in GWT client-side code.

What is standard/recommended way of doing this conversion, then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543832/convert-string-to-date-on-gwt

Comment: check if [Date Time Format](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) is helpful?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As given an example in [`Date Time Format`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html), this may be helpful.

```
public class DateTimeFormatExample implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    Date today = new Date();

    // prints Tue Dec 18 12:01:26 GMT-500 2007 in the default locale.
    GWT.log(today.toString(), null);

    // prints 12/18/07 in the default locale
    GWT.log(DateTimeFormat.getShortDateFormat().format(today), null);

    // prints December 18, 2007 in the default locale
    GWT.log(DateTimeFormat.getLongDateFormat().format(today), null);

    // prints 12:01 PM in the default locale
    GWT.log(DateTimeFormat.getShortTimeFormat().format(today), null);

    // prints 12:01:26 PM GMT-05:00 in the default locale
    GWT.log(DateTimeFormat.getLongTimeFormat().format(today), null);

    // prints Dec 18, 2007 12:01:26 PM in the default locale
    GWT.log(DateTimeFormat.getMediumDateTimeFormat().format(today), null);

    // A custom date format
    DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
    // prints Monday, December 17, 2007 in the default locale
    GWT.log(fmt.format(today), null);
  }
}
```